# Макроопределения в Microsoft Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как в Microsoft Visual Studio C++ определить дефайн, который был бы виден из всех файлов проекта?

Comment: вероятно, так же, как и в других IDE, нет?

Comment: Вероятно. А как в других IDE?

Comment: исходя из вашего вопроса можно заключить, что то, как это делается где бы то ни было, кроме VC++ вам известно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project -> project_name Properties... (Alt+F7) -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions. Добавляйте свое.

Если используются прекомпилированные заголовки, то можно объявлять свои дефайны в stdafx.h, т.к. его он принудительно должен включаться во все файлы исходного кода.

Ну, или сделайте такой заголовочный файл, который вручную везде инклудьте =)